# Selenium Java- check if value of results is greater than 900

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, assert

I got a tag on a webpage which will is a string which contains a number like as "Showing 1 – 40 of 9,814 results for" .

I want to make an assertion that the value is greater than 900.How can it be done.The HTML part of the page is

```
<span class="_10Ermr">Showing 1-40 of 9,814 results"</span>
```

Any way of doing thiss?

Comment: Are you able to extract this `Showing 1-40 of 9,814 results` using selenium ?

Comment: Nope. I'm unable to extract it actually.I tried to extract this using xpath and  getText() method but idk im getting some error.

Comment: Please share the code of that getting text

Comment: @Saiprakash: What's the error? Which xpath did you try? Is it unique in HTMLDOM?

Comment: String s=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[@id='container']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]")).getText();

Comment: Your only problem is locating the span element, Please share URL or page source code or see https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/

Comment: The url is --   https://www.flipkart.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way with the chromedriver on python. In the code replace `chromedriver_path` with the path of your driver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path))

driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=piraso')

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Showing")]')
number_of_results = int(element.text.split('of ')[1].split(' results')[0])
limit = 900
print(f'There are {number_of_results} results, ', end='')
if number_of_results >= limit:
    print(f'higher or equal than the limit {limit}')
else:
    print(f'lower than the limit {limit}')
```